# How To Ensure A CheckBox Is Checked Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

This is my html Code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" />
```

Here i want to check if the checkbox test is checked or not when clicking on that checkbox.

That means there have function to call when clicked the checkbox and in that function check the test is checked or not using javacsript.

How can i do this?

Comment: Do you want to test the *checked* state before or after the click changes the checkbox state?

Comment: `<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" onClick="check(this)" />`<br/>
In your java script : <br/> ` function check(element) {  alert(element.checked); } `<br/> Hope this will help you.

Comment: i want to call a function onclick() of checkbox and in that function i need to check wheather it is checked or not.

Comment: see the above comment @user1229903

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="checkbox" name="test" id="test" onClick="check(this)" />`
In your script :

```
  function check(element) {

        alert(element.checked); 
}
```

Hope this may help you, if not let me know.

Answer (score 0):

The answers of this question kind of make me feel down. I thought that one thing jQuery learned to everybody was at least to **not** use inline event handlers for the sake of [unobtrusive javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

With unobtrusive javascript, cross-browser, here is a way to do it:

```
document.getElementById('test').onclick = function() {
    alert(this.checked)
}
```